# Why QList is not working as model to QML GridView?

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, qml

I have problem setting the model to `GridView` in QML from C++ side. From the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-gridview.html#model-prop) about setting Model to GridView in qml it says:

> If a C++ model class is used, it must be a subclass of
> QAbstractItemModel or a simple list.

In my case my data is numbers in matrix (9x9), so I thought easiest way would be using simple list of integers as model in my QML GridView. My QML GridView is:

```
GridView
{
    id: gridView
    width: root.gridSize
    height: root.gridSize
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
    model: gridModel
    delegate: Text { text: modelData }
}
```

And in `main.cpp` for test I tried this way:

```
QList<int> test;
test << 1 << 2 << 3 << 4 << 5 << 6 << 7 << 11;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("gridModel", QVariant::fromValue(test));
```

And this is not working, and data is not displayed in qml. Also if I try `QList<QString>` data is not displayed in QML.

But if I try with using `QStringList` like this, it is working:

```
QStringList test;
test << "1" << "2" << "3" << "4" << "5" << "6" << "7" << "11";
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("gridModel", QVariant::fromValue(test));
```

What I am doing wrong? And why `QStringList` works but `QList<QString>` is not working? Since QStringList inherits from QList, does it mean that it should be the same like `QList<QString>`? My goal is to use list of integers as model to the gridview but this confused me with the strings too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to use [`QVariantList`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#QVariantList-typedef):

```cpp
QVariantList test;
test << 1 << 2 << 3 << 4 << 5 << 6 << 7 << 11;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("gridModel", test);
```

On the other hand, the conversion of `QList<int>` and `QList<QString>` to the QML Array in a transparent way is valid, that can be verified because the elements can be accessed using `[]` in addition to the fact that the object has the `length` attribute.

The problem seems to be that the views only support the classes that it inherits from QAbstractItemModel, QStringList, QVariantList, and numbers, and not the other items.

Comment: thank you so much for solution and explanation about QList.